# Messaging queue like solution but for running a job not queuing one

Tags: java, cron, jobs

I need to have a set of jobs running but they won't be queued like how something like RabbitMQ (or similar software) works. They will run continuously and perform some action periodic (like a cron job) while making sure they don't overlap. So if a job doesn't finish until it's scheduled to run again it won't start again so we end up with same job running twice.

Is there any software that can handle and provide such features so i don't end up with a script while (true) {do...}

Comment: it does look like what I need. Thanks. Maybe add this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that [DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) is what you are looking for as part of the 
[Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) API